# To reconcile ancient beliefs to the modern: new tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Since Hinduism is an ancient faith there is bound to be skepticism with changing times. Believers are often unwittingly charged with a responsibility to interpret and moderate several ancient Hindu scientific ways of life, philosophy and  viewpoints to reconcile it with relevance into modern viewpoints.

I therefore suggest a new sub-tag *Skepticism* as it is not in the list at present.

Comment: I think 'skepticism' is considered as a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: If should show up on typing the letters on this Hinduism site  tag space.

Comment: First it's a meta tag and second it can go wrong way too easily.

Comment: My point is that skepticism tag should show up on this site which it does not. There is imho a great deal of skepticism about Hindu beliefs, practices etc. which is bound to be there because (again imho) the religion is ancient, has no single prophet as a head or as a pioneer..